# How to load themes file properly using php

Tags: php, xampp

Talking about my project I am working, its just a simple website in localhost.I am Xampp server rand inside htdocs my website is in file `creative` which contains `index.php` file and another sub directory `themes` which further contains themes folder which contain all the necessary `html` `php` and `css` files that builds my websites.

When a user enters I want to redirect him from the `index.php` in `localhost/creative` to the index.php in `localhost/creative/themes/theme-folder`. I tried to use `require_once('creative/themes/theme-folder/index.php');` but in most of cases it fails. is there any other way to do so.

Comment: That should happen automatically if you have an installed active theme

Comment: you `index.php` in `localhost/creative` should only contain the normal contents of wordpress index though.. like `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );` and `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Comment: @Stender sorry its not wordpress . I am working on staic pages.

Comment: Then why did you add the tag `wordpress`?

Comment: Sorry @Stender my mistake click

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the .httpd file. 
Then you add:

```
#The path of your repositories:
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/creative" 

#then you make an alias:
Alias /creative "C:/xampp/htdocs/creative/themes/theme-folder"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/creative/themes/theme-folder">
    #Modify this data according to your needs
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Yes I could do so. But at first the `index.php` in `localhost/creative` must open in order to set up the environment. And after all processing it should redirect to the theme file.

Comment: what do you see when you try to access to localhost/creative ?

Comment: It just open `index.php` I want to pass the user to `localhost/creative/theme`

Comment: do you are using JavaScript?
if so, try window.location = "http://localhot/creative/themes/theme-folder/index.php"

Comment: header('Location: http:/localhot/creative/themes/theme-folder/index.php');